# Relativistic free fall

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, spacetime

if I wanted to calculate how far a proton moving at horizontal speed of $0,96 c$ would fall (due to gravity $g$ vertically) passing through a space of $1$m (horizontally) - how do I calculate that? Do I need to use special relativity? Probably.. how do I do that?

Could I even use "normal" newtonian thoughts (as an approximation)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relativity, an inertial frame of reference is a free-falling frame. In such a frame, there are no (local) effects of gravity. Suppose we adopt such a frame that has no horizontal motion relative to the lab. Then the floor of the lab is accelerating upward at $g$. Therefore the result is exactly what you would have expected from Newtonian physics: $(1/2)gt^2$, where $t$ is the time of flight.